# "The software on this computer is up-to-date" popping up every few minutes

Tags: notification

I know the same question has been asked, but that was 9 years ago. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and I really don't feel like upgrading to 22.10. Is there a way I can solve this issue?

EDIT: The issue appears to have been resolved. I run a sudo apt-get update and I haven't had the pop-up since.

Comment: It was asked in the last 3 days as well.

Comment: That is a message from `Software Updater`. Using the command line, Check `$HOME/.config/autostart/*`, `crontab -l`, the startup files for your `$SHELL`. Do `man $SHELL` and search "`STARTUP FILES`". Do `sudo journalctl--since="-6 minutes"` within 5 minutes of the pop-up.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add whatever info you get. Don't use Add Comment, or you'll classify yourself as "Does Not Follow Instructions (DNFI)", and I'll ignore you. I view DNFIs as unhelpable.